# Maintain initial state of a form

Tags: reactjs, state

while learning react i made menus and on a menu click i open a form.  i want to have a 'close' icon on form which when pressed closes the form and again on menu click opens it.

i made a parent component which handles the state of form(child component). it manages showchild = true or false.

```
//this is button defined on form compenent
 <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Self Close</button>


//this is parent component
import React from 'react';
import DemoForm from './form';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    closeChild = () => {
      this.setState({
        showChild: false,
      });
    };

 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        showChild: true
      };
    }
   render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.showChild && <DemoForm onClose={this.closeChild} />}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default ParentComponent;
```

this works fine, on button click the form closes, i have checked react, the state of form changes from showchild true to false. the problem is for next time when i try to click menu to open this form, the form doesn't open. because the state of showchild = false.

can we change state of form to showchild = true once the form is finally close or any other technique.

how can i achieve this? i am still on react and redux is next goal. can i do this with react state management.

Comment: Can you show the code for the logic of opening the form?

Comment: it is simple from react-router-dom

Answer (score 1):

You just change that `closeChild()` function to `triggerMenu()`, so when its open it will close, and when its closed it will open:

```
    triggerMenu = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            showChild: !prevState.showChild
        })
    };
```

Comment: @Phillip yep sorry, i missed it. Editer the answer, thank you

Comment: `closeChild = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            showChild : !prevState.showChild
        }));
    };`       i did this but still the same, cant open form 2nd time.

Comment: @RanuVijay that should work, make sure you point `onClose` and `onClick` both to `closeChild`. Because this code is updates the state from `true to false` and from `false to true`

Comment: @ErtanHasani  when i check react developer tool to know the state of form after i click on button it shows "showChild : false" and this is the reason i can't open it second time.

Comment: ` <button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Self Close</button>`from form and   `<DemoForm onClose={this.closeChild} />` from parent component is already pointing to closeChild

Comment: @RanuVijay yes it shows false, and than that method should check it back to true. Try to add more code. You should have another button that has onclick event pointed to `closeChild()`, to show it\